# How to let all the pagestyle of pages from \frontmatter to \mainmatter empty

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, front-matter

`\frontmatter` may include

- Table of Contents
- List of Figures
- List of Tables
- Preference
- and other parts

Now, I want to set up the pagestyle of **pages** range from the tag `\frontmatter` to the tag `\mainmatter` be **plain**. that is said all of  `\tableofcontents`,`\listoffigures`,`\listoftables`,`preference` parts should not contain page number, page head, page foot. I dont want to set them one by one with `\thispagestyle`.
the `\pagestyle` of all **pages** in `\mainmatterpart` should be **fancy**.

I think if I can deal with `\frontmatter`, I also can apply the method to `\mainmatter` to `\backmatter`.

Am I right?

Comment: This is not clear (to me).  Do you want to change the pagestyle so that different pagestyles are used in `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter`?  If so, why can't you define three different page styles?

Comment: @jon I want to set all pages[\frontmatter, \mainmatter] no page number, no page head,no page foot

Comment: Why don't you put `pagestyle{empty}` in your preamble? Also you have to redefine page style `plain` to be `empty` to have similar effect on chapter pages too.

Comment: pythonee -- @HarishKumar has the right idea.  (Sorry, I misunderstood your goals.)

Comment: @HarishKumar Sorry for my poor English. I explain once again. pages[\frontmatter, \mainmatter] -> pagestyle{empty}, pages[\mainmatter,\backmatter] -> pagestyle{fancy}, pages[\backmatter, ....]->pagestyle{empty}

Comment: @jon see the previous comment

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Getting pagestyles to be 'empty' is easy, but how can the 'mainmatter' be both `\pagestyle{empty}` and `\pagestyle{fancy}`? And what does 'pages[\backmater, ...]' mean?  (That is, what does the '...' repreesnt?)

Comment: @HarishKumar I have re-edited the problem. I hope this version clarified

Comment: @jon See the new version of question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the revised version of the question, you (may) want:

```
\documentclass{book}                                                        
\usepackage{lipsum, fancyhdr}                                               

\begin{document}                                                            

\pagestyle{empty}                                                           
% pagestyle{plain}                                                          
\frontmatter                                                                

\lipsum[1]                                                                  

\mainmatter                                                                 
\pagestyle{fancy}                                                           

\chapter{1}                                                                 
\section{1}                                                                 
\lipsum                                                                     


\backmatter                                                                 
\pagestyle{empty}                                                           
%\pagestyle{plain}                                                          

\lipsum[1]                                                                  

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** If you want to wrap these changes into a `.sty` file, you could do this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]                                        
\ProvidesPackage{myfile}                                                    
  [2012/05/02 v0.01 modifications to the *matter commands]                  


\RequirePackage{etoolbox}                                                   
\appto\frontmatter{\pagestyle{empty}}                                       
\appto\mainmatter{\pagestyle{fancy}}                                        
\appto\backmatter{\pagestyle{empty}}                                        


\endinput
```

Name this file `myfile.sty` and load it in the preamble of your document with the usual `\usepackage{myfile}`.  Note that the name of this file is arbitrary, and the first three lines as well as the last line are not strictly needed.

However, I do not really see the advantage of hard-wiring such changes into the `\*matter` commands, even if I agree with the idea that generic formatting changes are often better put into a `.sty` file for complex documents.

Comment: How can I define this on style file?

Comment: You could, I suppose, patch the `\*matter` commands, but you still need to use the actual `\*matter` commands in your document: how would TeX know otherwise that it is entering a new part of the document?

Comment: thank you for your reply and patience. But I'm a beginner of tex. I dont know how to patch the \*matter in style file. Can you give me more details or document may help.

Comment: @pythonee -- see the revised answer.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the `etoolbox`?  I'm using KOMA-Script

Comment: @MarioS.E. -- Are you sure you're not already using `etoolbox`?  Lots of recent packages already use it themselves. (Obviously other packages by the same author, such as `csquotes` and `biblatex`, but others too: a quick, and therefore not competely accurate, `grep` of the .sty files in TeX Live 2013 turns up 177 hits.)

Answer (score 4):

Following will make the changes in the document as your question demands.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%%-define header and footer for main matter
\fancypagestyle{headings}{%
  \fancyhf{}   % Clear all headers and footers first
  %% Right headers on odd pages
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{My right heading}%you can use \leftmark or right mark as per need.
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{My left heading}%you can use \leftmark or right mark as per need.
  \fancyhead[C]{Center} 
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Me}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

%% -------define pagestyle {plain} to be {empty} (without using fancyhdr)
 \makeatletter
 \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
 \makeatother
%----------------------------------------------
\title{My title}
\author{Me}
%----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%----------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{empty} % declare all pages to have empty header and footer.
%----------------------------------------------
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
%----------------------------------------------
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  %% Clear all headers and footers
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%----------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{headings}

\mainmatter


\part{Hello World}
\clearpage
\chapter{Test one}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{My section one}
\lipsum[1]
\part{Goodbye World}
\chapter{Test two}
\lipsum[1]
\section{My section two}
\lipsum[1]
%----------------------------------------------
\backmatter

%%---Redefine plain page style now using fancyhdr for a change
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  %% Clear all headers and footers
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%  \makeatletter
%  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
%  \makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
%----------------------------------------------
\chapter{Test one}
\lipsum[1]
%----------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd add a section for `\backmatter` just to be complete.

Comment: @jon: Added, but the answer is, I think, still to be modified as I have lot of confusions remaining.

Comment: No doubt! The question still needs to be clarified.